# Avoid Sencha cmd upgrade while Sencha app build

Tags: build, upgrade, sencha-cmd

During Sencha build process I always require to upgrade Sencha cmd up-to its latest version.
Can we avoid upgrading Sencha cmd version?

Used command:

```
sencha app build classic
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Find out the version numbers

In your ExtJs workspace folder you could find the file `<workspaceDir>/.sencha/app/sencha.cfg`. 
If you search for the value of `app.cmd.version` you know which Sencha Cmd version was used to build your app.

Usually this version should match your active Sencha Cmd version. If you execute `sencha help` on command line you will get the installed version.

#### Switch between Sencha Cmd versions

If you have multiple ExtJs apps with different Sencha Cmd versions, you also could install multiple Sencha Cmd versions on your machine.

Execute the following command in your terminal:
`sencha switch -l`

Here you will get a listing of all your installed versions. And with the following command you can switch versions:

`sencha switch 6.2.103`

With this in mind you can match your active Sencha Cmd version with your app cmd version before you start the build process.

Comment: Thanks a lot , installed sencha cmd version and app workspace version was different .